# How to convert unicode in java to correct CHARSET to print on a LINE-PRINTER

Tags: java, unicode, printing, data-conversion

I'm using direct printing to my Star TSP700 printer. The printer is set to 852 Latin-2. So, before I send a text to printer, I convert it to "IBM852", but it doesn't working. I get a lot of unwanted/unknown chars between characters. This happens where the printer prints Š,Č,Ž and š,ž,č. I believe to be a problem with UNICODE string representation and a printer accepting ASCII chars? Can anybody help?

Converting to IBM852

```
public static String c( String p_tekst, String p_cp ) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
  byte b[] = p_tekst.getBytes( p_cp );
  String w_charset;
  w_charset = new String(b);
  return w_charset;
}
```

Writing to printer - I send a converted string as:

```
FileWriter out = new FileWriter("lpt3");
out.write(...);
out.close();
```

Comment: Well the first problem is that you're using `FileWriter`, which will actually use your platform-default encoding. Is there any reason you're doing this rather than using the Java printer APIs?

Comment: Not really - as I'm a new in java programming. Can you direct me to some examples witch will do the trick?

Comment: I'd start off by searching for "printing in Java" or the like. Although those are primarily around printing documents from graphics etc. I'll add an answer around text... (Or I would, but Mike's answer is fine.)

Comment: As an aside, it's definitely worth working on your naming. A method called `c` is hardly self-describing :)

Answer (score 1):

<sup>I would think that there must be ways to learn about character encodings in java without wasting lots of paper, but if you really *must* do this, then:</sup>

You need to use the overload of `getBytes()` which accepts a `String charsetName` as a parameter, so as to obtain an array of bytes in the `852 Latin-2` charset. Then, you must *not* convert that back into a string again; instead, you need to write these bytes to the printer using an `OutputStream`.

Alternatively, you can write your strings directly to the printer by using an `OutputStreamWriter` which you have constructed for the right `Charset`.

**Edit**

Here is an example.  I am not trying it, because I don't want to waste paper.  I assume that your "lpt3" works, since you say that you managed to print something, albeit in the wrong charset.

```
public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception
{
    Charset charset = Charset.forName( "Cp852" );
    try( OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream("lpt3") )
    {
        try( Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter( outputStream, charset ) )
        {
            writer.write( "╔════════════════════════════════════════╗" );
            writer.write( "║ this will be printed in MS-DOS Latin-2 ║" );
            writer.write( "╚════════════════════════════════════════╝" );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Any examples, please?

Comment: @Matej I amended my answer.

Comment: Mike thank you. I've busted my head for hours and probably read every post on the net with relevant tags. It works perfectly.

Comment: Glad to be of help, Matej !

Comment: Mike another question about the above solution. When a printer is not ready or turned off,... it takes about 5 min before java throws an error. Is there a way to speed this up?

Comment: I don't know.  I doubt that you can control this from java.  This is probably a system configuration issue.  Googling "lpt timeout" appears to be yielding some results that you might find useful.